# Rotate Windows Store XAML control using an custom Panel

Tags: xaml, windows-8, rotation, windows-store-apps

I am using a custom Panel, very similar to a [radial panel](http://jobijoy.blogspot.it/2008/04/simple-radial-panel-for-wpf-and.html).

I was wondering if there was a way to rotate the items as well as position them.

I know I could use different item templates, but that would require assigning the templates during coding.  I'm looking for a runtime solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was create an item template that rotates the item based on a data bound property in the CLR object.

In order to rotate in a windows store app, I used [a modified LayoutTransformer](http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/)